# Is "restaurant I ordered from" idiomatic?

Tags: grammar, idiomatic-language

Is "restaurant I ordered from" idiomatic? I am not sure if it's correct, but I see a lot of people saying it, but I don't think it's grammatically correct. Don't you "order food at a restaurant"? However, I see "order from a restaurant" more often on Google than "order at a restaurant".

For example:

> The restaurant I ordered from was just a few miles away from my
>   apartment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both "from" and "at" are grammatically correct and idiomatic.  "at" works because you are located "at" the restaurant. "from" works because the food comes "from" the restauarant.

You say "I see a lot of people saying it".  If these are English speakers, then the fact that lots of people use this expression makes it correct, at some register.

Comment: You might order **from** a restaurant, when you are not there, by phone or using a phone app, either for collection or delivery.